# iPhone animated banner : which framework to use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graphics, opengl-es

I'm willing to create a little frame to display animated ads in my app.
It could be simple little animations, or "3D" transition between ads, or combination of both.
I'm not familiar with graphic frameworks, I just used CoreGraphics, which I think is not optimized for that.
I thought of OpenGL, but maybe that's too much and takes too much ressources just for this little thing.
What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of animation are you talking about?  Do you mean the ads themselves are animations, or you're animating old ads out and new ones in, etc?

Assuming the latter, UIView's animation class methods are probably by far the easiest to implement/use.  See the Animations section of the guide here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Actually I'd like to do both, and I thought about the UIView's animation, but since i'd also like to have little animations. I also thought of a WebView with a video in HTML5, but not sure it will display how I want (no play/pause, adaptable resolution to devices,...) and I'm not sure wether I can preload animations and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically display Ads, then iAds framework is the way to go.But i doubt you would be able to use 3D animations in it.Secondly as Apple has provided iAds to display ads i dont think using other frameworks for that purpose is advisable.

Cheers

Aditya

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we have several customers who asked for different advertising solutions than iAd, that's why we want to create our solution. Cheers